# Good resources for experienced web developers moving to PHP?

Tags: php

Good morning, all.

I've been doing websites now for about seven years (most of which have been in ASP.NET, but some just HTML) and I'm getting ready to make the move to PHP for my next project.  Can anyone suggest some resources and/or tutorials that are more than the usual Hello World kind of thing?

Specifically, any guidelines on code re-use like the ASP.NET equivalent of MasterPages, UserControls, etc.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Don't. Seriously, know it or not, you get a lot of structure from ASP.NET that you take for granted. PHP is a mess. You *can* do certain advanced things but even just on a language basis, it's a joke. If you have the choice, choose something with a real language behind it like Django (Python is awesome) or Ruby on Rails. Much faster for building websites and they're maintainable (something that is painful 6months on in PHP).

Comment: To people reading the above: I'm not ragging on PHP just because I hate it - I used it professionally for many years after years on ASP.NET. I have done this exact migration and was very unhappy with it. I wish Django was as mature as it is now back then. I'd be happier and richer now.

Comment: I would prefer to stick with ASP.NET but unfortunately my client gets their hosting through a business partner that doesn't offer Microsoft products.  I told them I'd still be able to do their site but it would take a bit longer and they were fine with that.

Comment: I'm not saying don't migrate - Just migrate to something else if you can. Django is miles better than ASPNET was when I used it (v2) IMO. But it's very different and that can be intimidating.

Comment: Hmm, based on the new close rules this four year old question should be closed. _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt,

Reference:

http://php.net

Environment:

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Tutorials:

[One PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

[On w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/default.asp)

Web Frameworks:

[Symphony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)

[CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

Also consider checking out Python and Ruby as alternatives for web development. They are more powerful than PHP since you can utilize them also for desktop apps and maintainance scripts, where is while it is possible to do in PHP, it's highly undesirable.

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)

[Python](http://www.python.org/)

Answer (score 2):

As a 5 year PHP coder that has yearned for the liberation of a "better" platform such as ASP.NET, I bid thee good luck.

By itself, you have nothing like MasterPages, UserControls, page execution cycles, handlers, etc. PHP is much more like ASP classic in that the script starts at the top and ends at the bottom. Everything in the middle can be anything you like, and if you want the kind of structure that ASP.NET offered you, then you'll have to implement it yourself.

As soon as you figure your way around the basics, get over the massive lack of organization of the standard library, accept that the bolt-on OOP is a bit clunky, learn to accept PHP for the monster that it is, and still at this point actually want to use it for something serious, you should look into a pre-made framework such as [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) or [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) (among others) that try to get most of the plumbing out of your way.

Comment: +1 for encouraging to use a framework. PHP is a mess. PHP used through a framework is an *organized mess*, which is quite better.

Answer (score 0):

For your "specifically" part, you want to step away from raw PHP and spend some time playing with one of the numerous frameworks that spawned to overcome PHP's lack of RAD features.

http://cakephp.org - http://www.symfony-project.org - http://framework.zend.com

They all have their own slants on templating (all frameworks do) but none (and this extends outside of PHP) follow the same ideas as Microsoft. Server and User controls are fairly unique techniques.

As I said in my comments, they're nowhere near as clean as "proper" web frameworks (django, rails, even webpy etc) but they do work a lot better than just hacking away on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As Oli mentions in the comments, PHP by itself is missing a lot of the structure you may be used to.  There are a number of PHP frameworks that help solve this problem.

Symfony (http://www.symfony-project.org/) is somewhat similar to Rails / Django if that's what you're used to.

Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/) is a much more open form solution, but better for certain projects.

That said, if you're diving into PHP by itself, the manual on http://www.php.net is fantastic.  I downloaded it and keep a link to it in my quicklaunch.